# Contour Plot in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to render an equation in the cylindrical coordinates, and I used the following codes:

```
With[{λ = 1, f = 50, R = 25},
 ContourPlot[
   -Mod[(Pi/λ)*(Sqrt[ρ^2 + f^2] - f), Pi] /. {ρ -> Norm[{x, y}], ϕ -> ArcTan[x, y]},
   {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R},
   Contours -> 20, ContourLines -> False,
   RegionFunction -> (Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2] < R &),
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False]]
```

However, I got a pattern which seems **not smooth** because points were sampled equally in the Cartesian coordinates. How can I get a smooth contour plot? Furthermore, can I plot such a pattern in the 3D coordinates? Thanks a lot.

Here is an example of the output that I would like:

[image]

Comment: I added your graphic as an example for you, as I know the site does not let you do that yet.

Comment: Tony, if my post fully answers your question please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) it.  If not, please tell me in what way it is lacking.

Comment: @ Mr. Wizard, I'll do that. You were good but the 3d plot was not exactly what I want. Probably I didn't describe it clearly. I intend to plot the same pattern in 3D coordinates, say, the target-sheet-shaped preservers. It seems to shear and/or rotate 2d graphics with certain viewpoint. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your function can be simplified:

```
FullSimplify[
  -Mod[(Pi/λ)*(Sqrt[ρ^2 + f^2] - f), Pi] /.
     {ρ -> Norm[{x, y}], ϕ -> ArcTan[x, y]},
  Element[x | y, Reals]
]
```

> ```
> -Mod[(Pi*(-f + Sqrt[f^2 + x^2 + y^2]))/λ, Pi]
> ```

Second, you appear to want a `DensityPlot` rather than a `ContourPlot`.

Third, you can get smoother graphics by increasing `PlotPoints`:

```
With[{λ = 1, f = 50, R = 25},
  DensityPlot[
    Mod[(Pi*(-f + Sqrt[f^2 + x^2 + y^2]))/λ, Pi],
    {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R},
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
    Frame -> False,
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    ExclusionsStyle -> Black,
    RegionFunction -> (Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2] < R &)
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or as a `Plot3D`:

```
With[{λ = 1, f = 50, R = 25},
 Plot3D[Mod[(Pi*(-f + Sqrt[f^2 + x^2 + y^2]))/λ, Pi],
  {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R},
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  PlotPoints -> 25,
  RegionFunction -> (Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2] < R & )
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Incorporating R.M's suggestions from the comments:

```
jet[u_?NumericQ] /; 0 <= u <= 1 := 
 Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan}, {13/21, Yellow},
  {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, u]


With[{λ = 1, f = 50, R = 25},
  ArrayPlot[Table[
    If[Norm[{x, y}] < R, Mod[(Pi*(-f + Sqrt[f^2 + x^2 + y^2]))/λ, Pi], None],
    {x, -25, 25, 0.1}, {y, -25, 25, 0.1}
   ], ColorFunction -> jet, Frame -> False
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Mr. Wizard, I can actually get the same figure as you shown. But I wanna cut out the corners, say, just show the circular patterns.

Comment: @Tony Sorry, I removed one too many options in my attempt to simplify things.  Please look again and tell me if this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tony I just noticed that `ϕ` (phi) does not appear to be used in the function.  What am I missing?  What do you intend?

Comment: @Wizard, you used ExclusionsStyle -> Black, it just covered the noncontinuous points in the figure. However if we mesh the grid in cylindrical coordinates, we will get a smooth figure. I know this can be done in MATLAB by using pol2cart. I'm wondering if there is a similar way in Mathematica.

Comment: @Tony I'm not familiar with MATLAB so I may not understand what you want.  What should be done with those discontinuities?  I thought painting them black was reasonable.  In the `Plot3D` graphic I just added they default to style `None` and appear transparent.  How would you have them drawn?  Can you put an image of the output from MATLAB on http://imgur.com/ ?

Comment: @Wizard, you were good; phi doesn't appear in the function indeed, the function just is a function of rho.

Comment: @TonyDong You don't see the exclusions in MATLAB only because you're doing a finite sampling without any consideration for the function's discontinuities. `DensityPlot` as Mr.Wizard used here is "aware" of the discontinuity, which is why we have to deal with `Exclusions`. If you instead sample the domain and plot it using `ListDensityPlot`, then you'll reproduce MATLAB's figure. Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9321152) if you want to reproduce the `jet` colorscheme.

Comment: Thanks, @rm -rf, alright, I got the point. I don't care much about the color map actually, you and Mr.Wizard did a great work though.