# ContourPlot3D in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: plotting

My function `x=x(k,phi)` is defined implicetly: `h3(x,k,phi)==0`. Function `h3` is defined through `NSolve`, so I cannot really express `x` through `k` and `phi`. I need to Plot this function in 3D:

[image]

But, I need to plot in cylindrical coordinates, so that `phi` is polar angle, `k` is radius.

Similar questions:

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/contour-plot-in-cylindrical-coordinates) explicit function was used. I need to plot implicit.

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19076/how-do-i-make-a-3dplot-using-cylindrical-coordinates) `ParametricPlot3D` was used. But again, function was explicit.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Comment: It should not be too hard to make the replacements `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]` and `ArcTan[x, y]` in the right places, no?

Comment: Oh, yes, that actually works!

Comment: See also the first example in [`TransformedField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedField.html)